# DNS error observed while performing API testing using karate framework

Tags: karate

While performing a get call for an api via karat observing DNS error when the proxies im using is commented but if i use the proxy it returns 401 error.

Below is the Following Code :

Feature File Code :

```
    Background:
    *url baseUrl
    *def someData = { user:'"myemailid"','ContentType':'application/json',"Accept": "*/*"} 
    *headers someData

    Scenario: SomeScenario
    Given path '/clients'
    When method GET
    Then status 200

Karate Config :

    function()
    {
    karate.configure('proxy','ip address')
    var config = {
    baseUrl:'some url' 
    }
    return config;
    }
```

Request Send to the server:
DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:

```
1 > GET url
1 > Accept: */*
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Content-Type: application/json
1 > Host: scrbmapdk007182:8080
1 > Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_141)
1 > user: "myemail"
```

Response is 502 with along with DNS error

Not sure where im going wrong because it is working via postman .Request send is same as in postman

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

Has to be in `http:` or `https:` URI form including port number if applicable:

```
karate.configure('proxy','http://myhost:80');
```

EDIT: for others landing here, besides the fact that an HTTP proxy may be in the picture - another place where Karate behaves a bit differently than Postman is that Karate [does not auto-send an `Accept` header by default](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/388#issuecomment-386845749).

Comment: Thanks Peter .Will check it out

Comment: Hi Peter,                                                                                                      
Observed the following  while trying to test the api locally                                            
                                                                                                                       
DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 
1 < 301
1 < Connection: Close
1 < Location: http://10.91.28.206
1 < Server: BlueCoat-Security-Appliance

Comment: @user3498245 this is impossible to diagnose without being able to replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - I suggest taking the help of someone who knows Java and debugging and contributing a fix to the karate code if needed - all the best !

Comment: Thanks Peter .Will try to figure it out